# Writing and reading inherited objects from a file with bufferred reader

Tags: java, inheritance, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am writing a librarian admin program and I have two classes: members and premium members. there is no real difference other than the fact that premium members can take out 5 books as opposed to only 3. I am using a buffered reader and writer to read these items but I am wonderring how (or If I can at all) read and write both objects to a single .txt file?

here's my code I have so far:

Member class

```
public String toString(int i) {
    String stg = "";
    stg += memID + "#" + name + "#" + surname + "#" + address + "#" + email + "#" + cellnum + "#" + num + "#" + accntTyp + "#" + pass + "#" + book1 + "#" + book2 + "#" + book3 + "#";
    return stg;
}
```

I have yet to do premium members class (wanted to get an answer while i do it) but it would pretty much look the same with an exception of 2 extra books.

Comment: That seems like bad design to me. I suggest only using a single class and having an `isPremium` flag or a `booksAllowed` variable. And please don't have 3 or 5 books variables, rather have an array or `ArrayList` or some other collection.

Comment: I do realize that something like that would be easier, however this is a school project and requires for me to use inheritance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - Are you asking how to do basic file reading / writing, how to identify the differences between the two in the file, how to write objects to files, how you **should** write them to file so you can identify them, how to avoid code duplication in your `toString` methods or something else?

Comment: What I am asking is how I can read from the file if there are 2 extra variables and therefor more things to read. Or in other words, how can I make sure it "knows" when to read the 2 extra variable and when not to?

As I was writing that^ I worked out an answer.
just using a simple "if" statement if accnttyp == "premium"